# Eliminating square root

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, radicals

I have a quantity $f=\sqrt{(a+b)^2-c}$ I need to know the explicit dependence of $f$ on the quantity $(a+b)$, is there any way of removing the term $-c$ from the square root and then compensate for it in a subsequent step?

Edit: All quantities are real and ${(a+b)^2-c>0}$

Comment: What do you mean by "explicit dependence?"  The expression is explicit.

Comment: There isn't in general, because as you can see the result changes very drastically depending on whether $c<(a+b)^2$ or $c>(a+b)^2$.  Do you know anything else about the behavior of $c$?  The simplest example would be that if you know $c\approx 0$ then $f\approx |a+b|$.

Comment: @Dr.MV The quantity (a+b) is composed of many terms in fact, and I needed to know the explicit dependence of f on some specific parameters included in it.

Comment: And now, what do you mean by "is composed of many terems?"  You have an explicit relationship between $f$ and $a$, $b$, and $c$.  Are you asking if the relationship is affine of linear? It is not.

Comment: @Dr.MV By "composed of many terms" I mean that a and b each is a polynomial of (s) and (v), two important parameters that I need to know the explicit dependence of (f) on them.